# Did Plato have a utilitarian view of religion?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, plato

I seem to remember while reading, from what I *believe* was the Republic, that Plato saw what could be interpreted a utilitarian role for Religion in society.

Am I misremembering?  Not asking what he believed or if he believed in religion but if he saw a role of religion.

Comment: Hint: The *justified true belief* definition of all important *knowledge* was said to be first coined by Plato for his system of philosophy...

Comment: Thanks for the lead but I don’t see how understanding what knowledge is, or belief for that matter, has to do with whether he saw a religion as useful in the republic or state

Comment: No one seems deny the importance of knowledge in a state, and since the essence of either knowledge or religion is the way of belief, so …